# Hibernate EntityManager: how to remove associations

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, associations, entitymanager

o Some idiomatic clarifications for a better understanding: *capa* means **layer** and *mapa* means **map**

o A layer might be used in different maps and a map might contain many different layers

o When you delete a layer, associations with maps must disappear, but maps themselves continue existing.

o Conversely, when you delete a map, associations with layers must disappear, but layers themselves continue existing.

o The mapping code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAPA")
public class Capa implements Serializable {    
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="capas")
    private Set<Mapa> mapas;
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MAPA")
public class Mapa implements Serializable {
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="mapa_capa", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="idMapa")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="idCapa")}) 
    private Set<Capa> capas;
}
```

o To remove the link between a layer(capa) and its maps (mapas), I've tried:

```
Capa c = findCapa();
Iterator<Mapa> itms = c.getMapas().iterator();        
while (itms.hasNext()) {
    Mapa m = itms.next(); 
    m.getCapas().remove(c);
    c.getMapas().remove(m);
    getEntityManager().refresh(m);                
    getEntityManager().refresh(c);   
}
```

And that does not work. Both sets (m.capas and c.mapas) remain untouched.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Your Capa `c` is one object. The persistence provider can only know the `c` actually exists in the set of `Mapa`, if you have implemented the `hashCode` and `equals` properly in your `Capa` class. Else, there might be a case, when hibernate will never know that `c` actually exists in `m` and hence `m.getCapas().remove(c)` will never actually remove `c` from `m`. You can check this by evaluating the returned value from the remove call. I am pretty sure it will be `false`.

The better thing to do here is to check the primary key of objects and then remove the `actual object` from the sets.

```
Capa c = findCapa();
Iterator<Mapa> itms = c.getMapas().iterator();        
while (itms.hasNext()) {
    Mapa m = itms.next();
    foreach(Capa c1 : m.getCapas()) {
      if(c1.getId().equals(c.getId())) {
        m.getCapas().remove(c1);
      }
    }
    //No need to remove m from c as Mapa is the owning side
    getEntityManager().refresh(m);                
    getEntityManager().refresh(c);   
}
```

This however has an extra for loop.

The best thing to do is to implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods in all your entities.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call to flush in order that the change will take affect in the database. you didnt call to flush and you call to refresh so the db copy override your change

Comment: thanks for your answer, it did not work. actually, before i posted the code i had it with flush.

Comment: did you look on the log to check if the sql fired to the database? you can use hibernaet log or hibernate show_sql or sql profiler for this.